# Error in writing a conditional regression equation as a legend in R

Tags: r, plot, legend

## Background

I'm trying to have a regression equation via`bquote` in the legend. Using **version # 1** (see R code below the picture) of my R code, I get the picture below.

**BUT**, I need **IF** `b` (see R code below the picture) is *"negative"* **THEN** the `+` sign will be removed. To achieve this criteria, I came up with **version # 2** (see R code below the picture) of my R code.

## Question

I'm wondering how to fix the error in my **Version # 2** R code (see R code below the picture)?
`Error: unexpected ')' in "       bty = "n")"`

[image]

**Version # 1:**

```
plot(1, ty = 'n')
a = .234; b = -.335
legend("center", legend = bquote(bold(Outcome[i] == .(round (a , 2))~ + ~.
(round(b , 2))~"\u00D7"~Predictor[i])), bty = "n")
```

**Version # 2:**

```
legend("center", legend = bquote(bold(Outcome[i] == .(round (a , 2))~ 
ifelse(.(b > 0), + , "") ~.(round(b , 2))~"\u00D7"~Predictor[i])), 
   bty = "n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the easiest fix (and what I normally do in such cases - in your case I am not even sure if you can call `ifelse` within `bquote`) is to use the `if-else` outside the call instead of inside.:

```
plot(1, ty = 'n')
a = .234; b = -.335

if (b > 0) {

 legend("center", legend = bquote(bold(Outcome[i] == .(round (a , 2))~ + ~.
                                       (round(b , 2))~"\u00D7"~Predictor[i])), bty = "n")

} else {

 legend("center", legend = bquote(bold(Outcome[i] == .(round (a , 2))~ .
                                       (round(b , 2))~"\u00D7"~Predictor[i])), bty = "n")

}
```

Output:

[image]